# Как удалить дубли с под массива?

Tags: php

Есть массив вот такого вида.

```html
Array
(
    [chat_9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 47
            [1] => 21
            [2] => 47
            [3] => 47
            [4] => 25
            [5] => 25
            [28] => 25
            [29] => 25
            [36] => 25
            [37] => 47
            [38] => 21
            [53] => 25
            [54] => 21
            [56] => 21
            [57] => 21
            [58] => 25
            [59] => 25
            [60] => 25
            [61] => 21
        )

    [chat_10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
            [1] => 21
            [2] => 21
            [3] => 25
            [4] => 21
            [5] => 25
            [6] => 25
            [7] => 21
            [8] => 21
            [9] => 25
            [10] => 25
            [11] => 21
            [12] => 25
            [13] => 21
            [14] => 21
            [15] => 25
            [16] => 21
        )
```

Как убрать дубли но так чтобы [chat_9] , [chat_10] остались, нужно удалить дубли которые находятся внутри них.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, ключи в массивах вас особо не интересуют. При использовании `array_unique` будет сохранен ключ первого из дубликатов. Если ключи следует убрать, то обернуть это еще в `array_values()`

```
foreach($data as $k => $v){
   $data[$k] = array_unique($v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```

Ответ взят отсюда
[Как удалить повторяющиеся значения из многомерного массива в PHP](http://qaru.site/questions/30492/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так:

```html
 <?php 

  //$chat_users_info - это массив в котором дубли удалить нужно. 

    $keys = array_keys($chat_users_info);
    $startfor = count($chat_users_info);
    $chat_users_complette = array(); //А это будет новый массив
    if($startfor != 0) { $startfor = $startfor - 1; }
    for($i=0;$i<=$startfor;$i++):
    

        array_push($chat_users_complette, [ "chat_".$keys[$i] =>array_unique($chat_users_info[$keys[$i]]) ]);
    
    endfor;


?>
```